# Setting array keys dynamically based on length

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Given an array in this format:

```js
[
  [{
      name: "name",
      value: "My-name"
    },
    {
      name: "qty",
      value: "1"
    },
    {
      name: "url",
      value: "test.com"
    },
    {
      name: "comment",
      value: "my-comment"
    }
  ],
  [{
      name: "name",
      value: "My-name2"
    },
    {
      name: "qty",
      value: "3"
    },
    {
      name: "url",
      value: "test2.com"
    }
  ],
  [{
      name: "name",
      value: "My-name3"
    },
    {
      name: "qty",
      value: "1"
    },
    {
      name: "url",
      value: "test3.com"
    },
    {
      name: "comment",
      value: "my-comment3"
    }
  ]
]
```

I'm looking to switch that to:

```js
[
  [
    { name: "My-name" },
    { qty: "1" },
    { url: "test.com" },
    { comment: "my-comment", }
  ],[
    { name: "My-name2" },  
    { qty: "3" },
    { url: "test2.com",
  ],[
    { name: "My-name3", },
    { qty: "1", },
    { url: "test3.com", },
    { comment: "my-comment3", }
  ]
]
```

In other words, swapping out the array keys but maintaining the object structure within each array element.

I've tried looping over each element and can swap the keys out using something like:

```
 newArray[iCount][item.name] = item.value;
```

However I'm then struggling to preserve the object order. Note that the comment field may or may not appear in the object.

Comment: This datastructure does not make sense to me

Comment: Note that your output array is missing a `}` and has a lot of unneeded `,` which can cause issues in IE. Also it would seem to make a lot more sense to have a single dimension array of objects, instead of a convoluted nested series of arrays, each containing multiple objects

Comment: What @Jonasw said. I'm willing to be you want a single array of objects rather than an array of arrays of objects.

Comment: Check my `moreBetterOutput` value in my answer. i think it may be better for you.

Comment: The data comes from a serilazied form output. However the inputs need to be split by type hence the funny output

Answer (score 1):

With `Array.map()` function:

```js
var arr = [  
   [{name:"name",value:"My-name"},{name:"qty",value:"1"},{name:"url",value:"test.com"},{name:"comment",value:"my-comment"}],
   [{name:"name",value:"My-name2"},{name:"qty",value:"3"},{name:"url",value:"test2.com"}],
   [{name:"name",value:"My-name3"},{name:"qty",value:"1"},{name:"url",value:"test3.com"},{name:"comment",value:"my-comment3"}]
],
result = arr.map(function(a){
    return a.map(function(obj){
        var o = {};
        o[obj.name] = obj.value
        return o;
    });
});
 
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check my `moreBetterOutput` value. I think will be better.

If you still need a result like your example in the question then you can check `output` value.

```js
const input = [  
   [  
      {  
         name:"name",
         value:"My-name"
      },
      {  
         name:"qty",
         value:"1"
      },
      {  
         name:"url",
         value:"test.com"
      },
      {  
         name:"comment",
         value:"my-comment"
      }
   ],
   [  
      {  
         name:"name",
         value:"My-name2"
      },
      {  
         name:"qty",
         value:"3"
      },
      {  
         name:"url",
         value:"test2.com"
      }
   ],
   [  
      {  
         name:"name",
         value:"My-name3"
      },
      {  
         name:"qty",
         value:"1"
      },
      {  
         name:"url",
         value:"test3.com"
      },
      {  
         name:"comment",
         value:"my-comment3"
      }
   ]
]

const output = input.map(arr => arr.map(obj => ({[obj.name]: obj.value})))

const moreBetterOutput = output.map(arr => arr.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
    acc[Object.keys(item)[0]] = item[Object.keys(item)[0]];
    return acc;
}, {}) )
//console.log(output);
console.log(moreBetterOutput);
```

Comment: @Jonasw because input is array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Another map function:

```
const result = array.map( subarray =>
 Object.assign(...subarray.map( ({name, value}) => ({ [name] : value }) ))
);
```